# MySQL is not accessible via remote client

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server, remote-access

I got the problem that my mysql, while locally (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) available, can't be reached via a remote client:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
```

but

```
telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3306
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I tried everything I found, but to no success. This is what I tried / checked:

**/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**

```
bind-address            = ::
mysqlx-bind-address     = ::
```

I also tried to set those addresses to "0.0.0.0", the result is the same

I also did a restart via `systemctl restart mysql` and `netstat -ntlup` shows

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      567829/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      567829/mysqld
```

**UFW is inactive**

```
ufw status
Status: inactive
```

**There is a mysql user with remote access**

```
SELECT user, host, account_locked, password_expired FROM user;
+---------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
| user    | host      | account_locked | password_expired |
+---------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
| my_user | %         | N              | N                |
```

This user has read permissions to all tables of a database. I executed a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

**Server accessibility**

The server generally is accessible from remote. I can connect via SSH and HTTP/HTTPS. I set the server provider firewall settings (Hetzner Cloud Server) and 3306 aswell as 33060 are allowed incoming ports.

I checked the MySQL server accessibility on the server itself via its remote IP, my local computer and from another external server. All show the above mentioned "Connection refused" via telnet and when trying to connect via the `mysql` command.

---

Those were all the tips and configurations I found on existing solutions of this problem. I am stuck for two days now and can't find a way forwards. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: */etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf* shows that only IPv6 is listening (and netstat confirms this). Comment these rows. Then check firewalls (local, remote, even intermediate).

Comment: in your host try `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'bind_address'` and see if it's the right address. use `0.0.0.0`

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'bind_address' ` shows `bind_address  | ::`. If I set `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`, it outputs `bind_address  | 0.0.0.0`, but the error is the same @sorrowpoetry.

If I comment out those lines, `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'bind_address'` outputs `bind_address  | *`, `netstat -ntlup` stays the same @Akina

Comment: everything is fine right now, I'm pretty sure it's a problem with `Hetzner` your hosting, try contacting them and making sure the port isn't blocked by their firewall. or you can try another port for Mysql. change the port in the settings to something else.

Comment: I will try this way, too. I tried to set a port forwarding from 3307 to 3306 and opened this port in the Hetzner firewall. I still can't connect. I will contact the Hetzner support and post an update here

Comment: was the same for me with docker-image -> check if remote is enable like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432504/how-to-connect-to-mysql-docker-container-on-a-remote-host-from-mysql-workbench